# Remove/delete/replace selected text in QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: qt, clipboard, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

I would like to delete the selected text inside a `QGraphicsTextItem`.

I have been searching all the classes it uses - like `QTextCursor`, `QTextDocument`... I can't find anything to remove text, except the `clear()` function of the `QTextDocument` which removes everything...

How can I remove the selection ?

```
    QTextCursor _cursor = textCursor();
    if(_cursor.hasSelection())
        ?
```

Alternatively (since I need this for a custom paste command), how can I replace the selection with an existing text or html ?

```
    QClipboard* _clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    const QMimeData* _mimeData = _clipboard->mimeData();
    if (_mimeData->hasHtml())
    {
        QTextCursor _cursor = textCursor();
        if(_cursor.hasSelection())
             ?
        _cursor.insertHtml(_mimeData->html());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not working `QTextCursor::removeSelectedText()`?

In the next example, we have at the beginning the text `QGraphics Text Item 1`, but as you will see, we can get the `QTextDocument` and also the `QTextCursor` for that document and insert some words.

After that, we move the cursor to the next word. Finally, we select the word under the cursor (`Text`) and remove it from our `QGraphicsTextItem`.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextDocument>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    QGraphicsTextItem* item_1  = new QGraphicsTextItem("QGraphics Text Item 1");
    item_1->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);

    QTextDocument* doc = item_1->document();

    scene.addItem(item_1);

    QTextCursor cursor(doc);
    cursor.beginEditBlock();
    cursor.insertText(" Hello ");
    cursor.insertText(" World ");
    cursor.endEditBlock();
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextWord);
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
    cursor.removeSelectedText();

    view.setFixedSize(640, 480);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```